# Finding details of externally-launched Python process

Tags: python, windows, process

I'm on Windows 7. I have a program that launches a Python script using the system Python interpreter. The process quickly finishes. I want a way to see the process, its command line arguments, and any other information about it. (PID?)

How can I do this? The process is killed before I could open Process Explorer. I can cause the program to launch the Python script whenever I want.

Comment: Can you modify or replace the script (to make it take longer, wait for a keystroke, log its own PID and the command line, etc)?

Comment: @npe I know how to solve the problem that way, I'm hoping for a way where I don't have to inject anything